# "Your Hitlers, your Stalins, all the greats."

Tags: phrase-meaning

I transcribed a podcast ad.

> I’m Robert Evans. I host a podcast called *Behind the Bastards* where we
> give in-depth histories about the worst people who ever lived. **Your**
> **Hitlers, your Stalins, all the greats**.

I wonder what 'your Hitlers' means here.

Does it mean the worst people who you think are as bad as Hitler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just means 'notoriously bad people such as Hitler and Stalin'.

*Your* here does not mean 'belonging to you' - it's just an informal usage for *the.*

INFORMAL - used to denote someone or something that is familiar or typical of its kind.
"I'm just your average man in the street" (Oxford Languages).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I feel a bit strange about classifying Hitler and Stalin as being among the 'greats', since this tends to have a positive connotation - I don't have that problem about Shakespeare, Mozart, Dickens, or Lana Del Rey.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I totally agree with you.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Presumably it was meant ironically.